# Which is faster? Concat 2 string then hashset contain or doing 2 hashset contains

Tags: java, string, performance, hashmap, hashset

I'm writing a high throughput java application and need your help settle a debate.
The application process strings at a very high frequency and I need to be able to check if the input contains a certain string.

The string is made up of two parts, part 1 and part 2. The two parts are concatenated with a space character.

```
var data = string1 + " " + string2;
```

To check if the input belong to my list, I have two approaches:

##### Approach 1:

```
Set<String> mylist;

...

void boolean isThere(String part1, String2 part2) {
   return mylist.contains(part1 + " " + part2);
}
```

##### Approach 2:

```
Map<String,Set<String>> mylist;

void boolean isThere(String part1, String2 part2) {
   var partA = mylist.get(part1);
   if (partA != null) {
      return partA.contains(part2);
   }
   return false;
}
```

The nature of the string parts are short-ish in nature, around 2 to 50 characters each.

Did some benchmarking with some mixed outcomes.

Comment: Have you considered a wrapper class containing the two string fields?

Answer (score 0):

There is going to be no significant difference between **HashSet** and **HashMap** because HashSet internally uses HashMap to store data.

Your 2nd approach makes no sense to me because you are storing a Set inside a Map just to check if it contains a string.

`contains()` method of HashSet has a time complexity of O(1) same as `containsKey()` of HashMap.

So use a HashSet i.e. your approach 1.

Read [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42530927/20430742)